# Force a div to go to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

I browsed the same question in SO, and none of them worked well [Cross Browser compatible] .
So, i'm looking for the same job to solve with jQuery.
I want to place the div at the bottom of the HTML page, not to the bottom of the screen.

I've tried with CSS only so far

```
clear: both;

min-height: 6%;

position: fixed;

bottom: 0;
```

`Edit`
My CSS

```
html, body {

margin: 0px;

padding: 0px;

height: 100%;

}

#footer {

 width: 100%;

 height: 6%;

 position: absolute;

 bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
}

#content {

float: left;

width: 59.5%;

height: 83%;

position:relative;

}

#news {
 z-index:2;
}

<html>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="news"> </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
<html>
```

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve with this? I think it might give some wiggle room for the possible solutions. I mean, you do explain what you want. Div at the bottom ..in what type of situations?

Comment: div at the bottom in every situation, no mater if text is of 1 line or 10000 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want sticky footer after all.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UYdXN/1/)

It uses [this sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Basic idea is to use that sticky footer or basically any `Sticky footer` and then color your `#wrap`, because it will cover the whole viewport vertically

Comment: i want to put the footer at the end of the page not at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: you got me right, just a little problem, by default i want to force it to go to the bottom of the page, but dont know how to set position of an element in jQuery

Comment: @Sourav What you want is infact _is_ a sticky footer.. unless im still lost, but i think im not. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set `height` of `body` and `html` to `100%`, then create a wrapper for the entire body that has `position: relative` and `height:100%`, when you have the element inside this wrapper it will align to the bottom.

```
<html
    <body>
        <div id="body-wrapper">
            <div id="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With CSS:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}

#body-wrapper {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Here is what happens without a wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj4c2/1/

And here it is with a wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/CPSt6/

Comment: You need one, the body won't expand otherwise, sorry.

Comment: can i use `min-height` in the wrapper instead of `height` ?

Comment: You can, but you'll still need a wrapper.

Comment: Actually, I think the height property is only needed for some browsers (most likely IE) but I can't really remember, was so long since I came out with this solution, works without it in chrome at least.

Comment: As I've said before, you must have a wrapper, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use position: absolute; bottom: 0px; That way div should be always on bottom of wrapping element. Wrapping element should have position: relative;

Comment: Its always good to have at least one main wrapper... or how else you know where your page ends? :-)

Comment: Actually, you don't need a wrapper. Just apply the position: relative; to the <body>.

Comment: No, that is wrong, setting position:relative on the body will not help, from w3.org: "The containing block for a positioned box is established by the nearest positioned ancestor (or, if none exists, the initial containing block, as in our example).", this means that the body will the nearest ancestor if no other element have a non fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the css document:

> An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.
>   An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is

src: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

so you should use position:absolute.

Comment: i tried with `position: absolute;

    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;` and it failed !